# How to unset my sms application as default app in Android

Tags: android, sms

I want to unset whether my SMS app as default app in android. I am following this tutorial:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

I can set my SMS app as default SMS app by the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to unset my SMS app as default app. How can I do that?

Here One point is to be noted : I have installed messaging classic app . From that app , I can unset my sms app as default . When this app is set as default and I tap on the SMS disabled textview The following pic is appeared .

[image]

I have tried the following :

```
getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
```

But the app is not unset as default app . What can I do ?

Comment: @MD , could you please give an answer to it ?

Comment: If no one answers, or is able to answer, would you keep on posting duplicate questions?

Comment: This question needs to be answered .

Comment: Will this question save the world? Or will it reveal something about the great mysteries of the universe? Of course every user expects her/his question to be answered. Thats why we post, does not mean we would keep on creating spam questions